# Navigate to root tab screen inside a tabnavigator - React Navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I have been using react-navigation for a while now. When I tried referring to this [Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@react-navigation/stacks-in-tabs) on Expo, I realised that if I navigate inside a tab, then I could not navigate back to Home Tab screen by pressing the Home button on the tabbar. I have to click on Back button that is present on the screen in order to navigate back to home.

Here is a piece of code:

```
const HomeStack = StackNavigator({
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
    Details: { screen: DetailsScreen },
});

const SettingsStack = StackNavigator({
    Settings: { screen: SettingsScreen },
    Details: { screen: DetailsScreen },
});

export default TabNavigator({
    Home: { screen: HomeStack },
    Settings: { screen: SettingsStack },
});
```

Referring to above code, if I click on `Settings` from the tabbar and then navigate to `Details` present inside that stack then I cant navigate back to `Settings` when I click on `Settings` again. I have to click on Back button that is present in the top section of the screen.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

It would be a good idea to use unique names for every new route. React Navigation uses these names as unique keys to differentiate between routes. I see a `Settings` in your default `TabNavigator`, and also another `Settings` for your `SettingsStack` `StackNavigator`. Same for `Details` too. (Simply renaming might solve your issue too, not sure).

So taking your example (and renaming `Settings` to `SettingsScreen`),

```
const HomeStack = StackNavigator({
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
    Details: { screen: DetailsScreen },
});

const SettingsStack = StackNavigator({
    SettingsScreen: { screen: SettingsScreen },
    Details: { screen: DetailsScreen },
});

export default TabNavigator({
    Home: { screen: HomeStack },
    Settings: { screen: SettingsStack },
});
```

Now, to go back to `SettingsScreen` from `Settings` > `Details`, you might wanna try

```
dispatch(NavigationActions.navigate({
  routeName: 'Settings',
  action: NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'SettingsScreen' })
}))
```

The idea is that in case of nested navigators, if you want to go back to another screen via the parent, you should call Navigations.navigate twice, in a nested manner.

It's in their docs somewhere. I'll try adding the link here for reference as soon as I find it.

Answer (score 0):

The tab navigator buttons only switch between the shown views. Since you navigated within your stack navigator, that's what you're seeing.

If you want to add the functionality that the stack is reset every time the tab button is pressed, you can do that by providing your own tab component and then calling `reset` on the stack navigator.

Comment: I connected with the folks of the library. They said it is a known missing feature. Follow up: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/3570#issuecomment-367593978

Answer (score 0):

```
createTopTabs = () => {
        return(
            <MaterialTopTabs.Navigator initialRouteName="Tab_Daily"
                tabBarOptions={{ 
                    showIcon: true, 
                    style: { backgroundColor: '#C4e672' },
                    labelStyle: { fontSize: 12, fontWeight: 'bold' },
                    /* tabStyle: { width: 100 }, */
                    tabStyle: { height: 50 },
                }}>
                <MaterialTopTabs.Screen 
                    name="Tab_ToDoNote"
                    component={TabToDoNote}
                    options={
                        {
                            title: '',
                            /* tabBarLabel: "Daily", */
                            tabBarIcon: () =>
                                (
                                    <Icons_SimpleLine
                                        style={
                                            [
                                                {
                                                    color: 'red',
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                        size={25}
                                        name={'note'}
                                    />
                                )
                        }
                    }
                />
                <MaterialTopTabs.Screen 
                    name="Tab_Daily"
                    component={TabDaily}
                    options={
                        {
                            title: '',
                            tabBarLabel: "Daily",
                            tabBarIcon: () =>
                                (
                                    <Icons_MaterialCommunity
                                        style={
                                            [
                                                {
                                                    color: 'red'
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                        size={18}
                                        name={'calendar-today'}
                                    />
                                )
                        }
                    }
                />
                <MaterialTopTabs.Screen 
                    name="Tab_Monthly"
                    component={TabMonthly}
                    options={
                        {
                            tabBarLabel: "Monthly",
                            tabBarIcon: () =>
                                (
                                    <Icons_MaterialCommunity
                                        style={
                                            [
                                                {
                                                    color: 'red'
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                        size={18}
                                        name={'calendar-month-outline'}
                                    />
                                )
                        }
                    }
                />
                <MaterialTopTabs.Screen 
                    name="Tab_Yearly"
                    component={TabYearly}
                    options={
                        {
                            tabBarLabel: "Yearly",
                            tabBarIcon: () =>
                                (
                                    <Icons_MaterialCommunity
                                        style={
                                            [
                                                {
                                                    color: 'red'
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                        size={18}
                                        name={'calendar-multiple'}
                                    />
                                )
                        }
                    }
                />
            </MaterialTopTabs.Navigator>
        );
    }
```

Comment: I would highly suggest adding an explanation to the end of your answer. Just code is not sufficient.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Also, please format your code so that it appears correctly in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to add `unmountOnBlur: true` to the tab which you want to clear